# How to show validation message below custom field in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, custom-options, validation

For my custom module i want to display validation message as like following image in product management. [image]

Can anyone suggest me a way to do this?

Comment: For this you can try key up function, 
something like count with key up, and then as they count reaches, 22 then do the action you want to perform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on Magentos JS `Validator` class in `js/prototype/validation.js` it validates and shows error messages and stops the form from submit, so this is not *exactly* what you need.

But they show messages under the form, so this functionality can be copied.

And to show the things, you can (as user6451 suggested) do something like:

```
function showLength(event) {
    var length = event.findElement().getValue().length
    // copied functionality to show it 
}

$('yourFormElement').observe('change', showLength);
$('yourFormElement').observe('keydown', showLength);
$('yourFormElement').observe('paste', showLength);
$('yourFormElement').observe('input', showLength);
```

Maybe this gets shorter, but I'm no prototype pro :D neither a JS pro ^^

I recommend to use prototype over jQuery, so you don'T have to add a new library in the backend, and this is quite easy to do.

Comment: Please check my updated question.I am trying to implement the same only.

Comment: Then you "just" have to place a `<div>` or `<ul>` under the form field and fill it with whatever you need. What is your problem here? I think the question is too broad

Comment: I need to add this to my custom tab added under product management.I have added some custom field under the tab.Need to validate one of them like this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#id").val().length
 });
```

Pass the id of the text filed there and set the condition